# Writing multiple matplotlib figures to PDF file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of Matplotlib figures that are saved as bytes in pdf format and base64 encoded. I wish to save these figures to a PDF file with the following code:

```
with open('result.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    for fig in f_list:
        f.write(base64.b64decode(fig))
```

The file is created successfully but it seems like only the last figure is saved to the file. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Can you append PDFs to each other like that? Do you have something like `poppler` installed? You could use `pdfunite` if you did.

Comment: `wb` overwrites the file. You can append with `ab`, but that doesn't fix your problem. That appends *bytes*. If you want to add *pages* to a PDF, then you'll need a Python library that knows how to do that.

Comment: If you have more than one fig in the list, they will all be written. How do you know there is only one? Are you using a pdf reader? You could sum the size of the decoded figures in the loop and see if that matches file size.

Comment: Turns out all the figures were being written to the file but only the last page was being displayed. I used PyPDF2 to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the figures are being written to the file but only the last page was being displayed. I had to use a [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/) to save and display all the pages.

The implementation is below:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter


writer = PdfFileWriter()
for fig in f_list:
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(fig)
    reader = PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(decoded_data)) # convert the figure to a stream object
    writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))

with open('result.pdf', 'wb') as pdf_file:
    writer.write(pdf_file)
```